# Java Recursion How To

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion

I have a class that just stores two integers:

```
public class Item
{
    private int from;
    private int to;

    public Item(int from, int to)
    {
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
    }
    getters and setters
}
```

At run time, I'm going to create a List of these Items. The list will contain between 1 and 21 values. I then need to loop through these values and do some processing. For example:

```
public void validate()
{
    List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
    items.add(new Item(1,3));
    items.add(new Item(11,13));
}
```

Or:

```
public void validate()
{
    List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
    items.add(new Item(1,3));
    items.add(new Item(11,13));
    items.add(new Item(21,23));
}
```

I then need to loop these values. Obviously I don't know how many levels to loop, so I can't hardcode a loop. If I could, the loops would look like this:

```
public void loop()
{
    String str;
    for(int i = 1; i < 3; i++)
    {
        str = "-" + i;
        for(int j = 11; j < 13; j++)
        {
            str = str + "-" + j;
            do stuff with str;
        }
    }
}
```

The output that I need to test against here would be:

-1-11
-1-12
-1-13
-2-11
-2-12
-2-13
-3-11
-3-12
-3-13

The second example would then be:

```
public void loop()
{
    String str;
    for(int i = 1; i < 3; i++)
    {
        str = "-" + i;
        for(int j = 11; j < 13; j++)
        {
            str = str + "-" + j;
            for(k = 21; k < 32; k++)
            {
                str = str + "-" + k;
                do stuff with str;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The output that I need to test against here would be:

-1-11-21
-1-11-22
-1-11-23
-1-12-21
-1-12-22
...
-2-11-21
-2-11-22
...
-3-13-21

Because I don't know how many loops there are, I think I need to use recursion.
However, I can't work out how to "do stuff with str" in the inner loop in recursion, and I'm beginning to think it's not possible.

This is kind of what I'm trying here:

```
private void recursiveExplore(List<Item> items, int depth)
{
    if (depth == 0) return;

    for (Item item : items)
    {
        for (int i = item.getFromParameterId(); i < item.getToParameterId(); i++)
        {
             do stuff here?
        }
        recursiveExplore(items.subList(items.size() - depth, items.size()), depth - 1);
    }
}

public void validate()
{
    recursiveExplore(items, items.size());
}
```

Any help appreciated.

ETA SSCCE:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MyTest
{
    private class Item
    {
        private int from;
        private int to;

        public Item(int from, int to)
        {
            this.from = from;
            this.to = to;
        }

        public int getFrom()
        {
            return from;
        }

        public int getTo()
        {
            return to;
        }
    }

    public void validate2()
    {
        List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
        items.add(new Item(1, 3));
        items.add(new Item(11, 13));

        String str;
        for (int i = items.get(0).getFrom(); i <= items.get(0).getTo(); i++)
        {
            for (int j = items.get(1).getFrom(); j <= items.get(1).getTo(); j++)
            {
                str = "-" + i + "-" + j;
                System.out.println(str);
            }
        }
    }

    public void validate3()
    {
        List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
        items.add(new Item(1, 3));
        items.add(new Item(11, 13));
        items.add(new Item(21, 23));

        String str;
        for (int i = items.get(0).getFrom(); i <= items.get(0).getTo(); i++)
        {
            for (int j = items.get(1).getFrom(); j <= items.get(1).getTo(); j++)
            {
                for (int k = items.get(2).getFrom(); k <= items.get(2).getTo(); k++)
                {
                    str = "-" + i + "-" + j + "-" + k;
                    System.out.println(str);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        MyTest test = new MyTest();
        test.validate2();
        test.validate3();
    }
}
```

Comment: Which version of Java do you use (JDK 1.4, 1.5, 6 or 7)?

Comment: There ara many errors. Please provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) example. It teaches you a lot and helps us help you.

Comment: I think you took the extremely complex path to solve this. Can you please tell me what is actually you want to achieve?

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: if you can do by recursive, then you can also do by iteration.

Comment: @reporter - JDK 1.5 with 1.6 compliance.

Comment: @jlordo I hoped the for loops above would be enough. i'll try and get an example together.

Comment: @RohitJain and Quoi - Apologies, I'd left out the outputs. I've added them in now. I basically want to generate those outputs, and then test if they exist elsewhere.

Comment: @AlexChard the code you showed us won't compile, because in `validate()` you declare a variable as `private`, which is impossible inside a method and have code like this: `items.add(new Item(1,3);` when 2 parenthesis open and only one closes, there is an error.

Comment: That's what I meant with your example not being [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Comment: @jlordo SSCCE now added.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want something like this

```
public class Item(){}

public class ListItem extends Item(){} //here you have a List of items
public class ObjectItem extends Item() {} //here you have only one item
```

So you can do a recursive search using the     instanceof operator .

Answer (score 0):

After checking your loops, I envisage you need to finally update the `str` variable with `-` in between. If so, then you are on write track.

```
private void recursiveExplore(List<Item> items, int depth, int str) {
    if (depth == 0) return;

    for (Item item : items) {
        for (int i = item.getFromParameterId(); i < item.getToParameterId(); i++) {
             str += "-" + i;
        }
        // Just need to concatenate the output of nested call
        str += recursiveExplore(items.subList(items.size() - depth, items.size()), depth - 1, str);
    }
    return str;
}

public void validate() {
    String finalStr = recursiveExplore(items, items.size(),"");
}
```

Not tried, but might need to tweak a little bit.

Comment: That's awesome, thanks. I was heading that way, but I hadn't worked out where the returns went. I'll modify my code now.

Answer (score 0):

I've worked out the code I needed with some help from a colleague (see below). It's not quite complete, but the main structure is there.
Thanks for all the help, I couldn't have done this without your help as well.

```
public void validateFiles()
{
    List<String> outputList = new ArrayList<String>();
    recursiveCompile(items, 0, null, outputList);
}

private void recursiveCompile(ArrayList<Item> items, int itemIndex,
        String compilation, List<String> outputList)
{
    if (itemIndex < items.size())
    {
        /* Get the item from the list. */
        Item item = items.get(itemIndex);
        /* Prepare the variables for the descent. */
        itemIndex++;
        if (compilation == null) compilation = "";
        /* Descend for each value in the from/to range. */
        for (int i = item.getFromParameterId(); i <= item.getToParameterId(); i++)
        {
            String s = compilation + "-" + item.getNextValue();
            recursiveCompile(items, itemIndex, s, outputList);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        /*
         * The bottom has been reached. Add the compiled string to the
         * output list and ascend (return).
         */
        outputList.add(compilation);
        return;
    }
}
```